# enumitem: How can I make a custom label for a specific entry in a list?

Tags: enumitem

I am writing a list of questions:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is a question.
    \item This is another one.
    \item This one is a hard one, I want to add an asterisk to the label.
    \item This one is another ordinary question.
\end{enumerate}
```

On the third entry, I want an asterisk in front of the label number. A naive approach would be this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is a question.
    \item This is another one.
    \item[*3.] This one is a hard one, I want to add an asterisk to the label.
    \item This one is another ordinary question.
\end{enumerate}
```

I would expect the output to look like this:

1. ...
2. ...

*3. ...

4. ...

However the output is this:

1. ...
2. ...

*3. ...

3. ...

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dirty solution. Separate into more `enum` and add `\setcounter{enumi}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is a question.
    \item This is another one.
    \item[*3.] This one is a hard one, I want to add an asterisk to the label.
    \end{enumerate}   
    \begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{3}
    \item This one is another ordinary question.
    \item And more\ldots
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item [*6.]This one is another hard question.
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{6}
\item And more\ldots
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another dirty solution: each time you want a star, redefine the macro `\theenumi` that prints the item number, and redefine it back to normal for regular items. Does not work with the `enumitem` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\let\olditem\item
\def\item{\def\theenumi{\arabic{enumi}}\olditem}
\def\itemstar{\def\theenumi{*\arabic{enumi}}\olditem}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is a question.
    \item This is another one.
    \itemstar This one is a hard one, I want to add an asterisk to the label.
    \item This one is another ordinary question.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]